# Consolidate an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array that looks like the following:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 10
>         [value] => 5
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 10
>         [value] => 1
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 11
>         [value] => 1
>     )
>
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 11
>         [value] => 1
>     )
> ```
>
> )

How can I consolidated the array by id? The resulting array I'm looking for would be something like:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 10
>         [value] => 6
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 11
>         [value] => 2
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a very efficient structure.  Have you considered consolidating it in this form?

```
array
(
    10 => 6,
    11 => 2,
);
```

That would allow fast key lookup on ID.

TO consolidate your first array into that form, just do this:

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $row)
{
    if(isset($array2[$row['id']]))
        $array2[$row['id']] += $row['value'];
    else
        $array2[$row['id']] = $row['value'];
}
```

Which would give you an array in the form of:

```
$array2 = array
(
    10 => 6,
    11 => 2,
);
```

If you **really** need it in your requested form, one more processing loop will get it there...

```
$array3 = array();
foreach($array2 as $id => $value)
{
    $array3[] = array('id' => $id, 'value' => $value);
}
```

So, there you go!

---

And more compact:

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $row)
    $array2[$row['id']] = (isset($array2[$row['id']]) ? $array2[$row['id']] : 0) + $row['value'];

$array3 = array();
foreach($array2 as $id => $value)
    $array3[] = array('id' => $id, 'value' => $value);
```